# 'on duplicate key' issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query :

```
INSERT INTO tx3_hu_villages (uid,vid,x,y,name,population) VALUES 
(122,2569,-29,36,'qwertzuiop',330),
(122,52915,-134,25,'asdfghjkléá',916)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
name=VALUES(name),population=VALUES(population);
```

It's works fine in MySQL Workbench, but in PHP I get this error :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL  server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

CREATE TABLE `tx3_hu_villages` (
  `vid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `x` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `y` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `population` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Without the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` works fine from PHP too.

Here is the PHP code :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table_name."_villages (uid,vid,x,y,name,population) VALUES ";

for($i=0;$i<count($v);$i++){

$sql.= "(".$v[$i]['uid'].",".$v[$i]['vid'].",".$v[$i]['x'].",".$v[$i]['y'].",'".$v[$i]['village']."',".$v[$i]['population']."),";

}

$sql[strlen($sql)-1] = "";

$sql.= "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=VALUES(name),population=VALUES(population);";

echo $sql;
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Can you show your PHP code? It seems like perhaps your query is not even getting passed for execution at all.

Comment: @MikeBrant Good catch, I was wondering why would SQL complain about an empty string somewhere in the query?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6428/1 works

Comment: Maybe put a space before `ON DUPLICATE KEY`?? It works without it in sqlfiddle, but perhaps your MySQL version doesn't like it.

Comment: Also, please post the query _exactly_ as it is echo'd by PHP. The query you have at the top isn't it, because it includes linebreaks....

Comment: I tried put space, almost everywhere :D Nothing changed :(

Comment: INSERT INTO tx3_hu_villages (uid,vid,x,y,name,population) VALUES (122,2569,-29,36,'qwertzuiop',330),(122,52915,-134,25,'asdfghjkléá',916) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=VALUES(name),population=VALUES(population);

Comment: $sql[strlen($sql)-1] = ""; Here is the problem :) Just changed to " " and its works...

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing those kinds of multiple inserts is to use PHP implode function like so

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table_name."_villages (uid,vid,x,y,name,population) VALUES ";

for($i=0;$i<count($v);$i++){

$temp[] = "(".$v[$i]['uid'].",".$v[$i]['vid'].",".$v[$i]['x'].",".$v[$i]['y'].",'".$v[$i]['village']."',".$v[$i]['population'].")";

}

$sql .= implode(',', $temp);

$sql.= " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=VALUES(name),population=VALUES(population);";

echo $sql;
```

Could potentially avoid those kinds of white space related issues.